# gitlab CICD pipeline(Sonarqube) trigger only for Merge Requests

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube, cicd, merge-request

Below CICD code automatically triggers when we push the code into "cicd-setup" branch. Here both "build-stage" and "sonar-stage" both automatically trigger when we PUSH the code into "cicd-setup" branch every time.
I don't want to trigger "sonar-stage" automatically, when we push the code.
I added
only:
- merge_requests
If i add above code, "sonar-stage" triggers only when we raise MR and other stages won't run when we raise MR and this is half solution!!.

**My Question is,** "sonar-stage" should not execute/trigger automatically when we PUSH the code every time. It will trigger ONLY when we raise Merge Request.

```
stages:
  - build-stage
  - sonar-stage

variables:
  SONAR_HOST: "http://asdftestserver01.abc.com:9000"
  SONAR_PROJECT_KEY: "test-api"
  SONAR_LOGIN_TOKEN: "aaabbbbbbcccccccddddddddd"

build_stage:
  stage: build-stage
  only:
    - cicd-setup
  environment:
    name: stage
  script:
    - echo "build stage started"
    - mvn clean install
    
api_sonarqube_analysis:
  stage: sonar-stage
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - cicd-setup    
  script:
    - pwd
    - echo "sonarqube started"
    - mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=$PROJECT_KEY -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 1):

As you may have seen on the docs, `only` and `except` are being deprecated in favour of `rules`. So perhaps is best for you to migrate to the new syntax - not that you can't achieve the same with `only` - as it'll also look clearer.

That said, you can adapt to the new format like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - build-stage
  - sonar-stage

variables:
  SONAR_HOST: "http://asdftestserver01.abc.com:9000"
  SONAR_PROJECT_KEY: "test-api"
  SONAR_LOGIN_TOKEN: "aaabbbbbbcccccccddddddddd"

build_stage:
  stage: build-stage
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "cicd-setup"
  environment:
    name: stage
  script:
    - echo "build stage started"
    - mvn clean install
    
api_sonarqube_analysis:
  stage: sonar-stage
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "cicd-setup"
  script:
    - pwd
    - echo "sonarqube started"
    - mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=$PROJECT_KEY -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN_TOKEN
```

I have used the variable `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` but you also have available `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` in case you want to use it. The full list of Merge Request variables available is [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines).

Bear in mind that this will generate two separate pipelines when you open an MR, one for each stage, as every push to an MR-related branch will also trigger `build_stage` job.

Comment: No worries! Let us know if that makes the pipeline work as you expected